# How to divide each column of a file by a row in a separate file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a large tab separated file that looks like this:

```
all.raw.data

genes DAR20150803d0 DAR20150803d19 DAR20150803d21 DAR20150804d0 ...
WG_115-M 442 388 230 439
WG_63 415 359 260 409
MG_556  247 220 119 268
...
```

I also have a file of read counts:

```
readcounts.txt

14
12
13
99
...
```

I would like to divide the first data column of `all.raw.data` by the first row in `readcounts.txt` and so on. My output should look like this:

```
genes DAR20150803d0 DAR20150803d19 DAR20150803d21 DAR20150804d0
WG_115-M 31.6 32.3 17.7 4.4
WG_63 29.6 29.9 20 4.1
MG_556 17.6 18.3 9.2 2.7
```

I have tried using awk, but I can't figure out how to read over each line of the `readcount.txt` file and then have the column with awk increase by one. I think my below attempt was the closest, but still won't work.

```
COUNT=1
while read p; do
    COUNT=$(( $COUNT + 1 ))
awk -v c=$p -v d=$COUNT '{ for ((i=d+1;i>=1;i--)) $i /= c; print }' OFS='\t' all.raw.done;
done < readcounts.txt
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t"; CONVFMT="%.1f" }
    NR==FNR { a[NR]=$1; next }
    FNR>1 { for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) $i /= a[i-1] }
1' readcounts.txt all.raw.data
genes   DAR20150803d0   DAR20150803d19  DAR20150803d21  DAR20150804d0
WG_115-M        31.6    32.3    17.7    4.4
WG_63   29.6    29.9    20      4.1
MG_556  17.6    18.3    9.2     2.7
```

Comment: Amazing! Does exactly what I need, thank you. Could you explain the steps?

Comment: You're welcome. I think it's all pretty self-explanatory, is there anything in particular that's not clear to you?

Comment: It helps for other people coming with the same question but perhaps not the same level of awk understanding. Then they can edit the parts for their own use.

Comment: I disagree. Anyone who knows awk basics will understand this at a glance and anyone who doesn't will get far more out of spending a few minutes with google and the man page (and adding some `prints` to see what values variables have if they find that useful) than me wasting my time spoon-feeding them the man page excerpts for this specific script. I'm happy to answer questions but I'm not going to spend twice as long documenting trivial scripts as it takes to write them.